# In C header tclPlatDecls.h where is TclPlatStubHooks defined?

Tags: c, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm porting tcl/tk C headers to D and i've run into a type that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Inside the file `tclPlatDecls.h` there is the following definition:

```
typedef struct TclPlatStubs {
    int magic;
    struct TclPlatStubHooks *hooks;

#ifdef __WIN32__ /* WIN */
    TCHAR * (*tcl_WinUtfToTChar) (CONST char *str, int len, Tcl_DString *dsPtr); /* 0 */
    char * (*tcl_WinTCharToUtf) (CONST TCHAR *str, int len, Tcl_DString *dsPtr); /* 1 */
#endif /* WIN */
#ifdef MAC_OSX_TCL /* MACOSX */
    int (*tcl_MacOSXOpenBundleResources) (Tcl_Interp *interp, CONST char *bundleName, int hasResourceFile, int maxPathLen, char *libraryPath); /* 0 */
    int (*tcl_MacOSXOpenVersionedBundleResources) (Tcl_Interp *interp, CONST char *bundleName, CONST char *bundleVersion, int hasResourceFile, int maxPathLen, char *libraryPath); /* 1 */
#endif /* MACOSX */
} TclPlatStubs;
```

I can't find the definition of `TclPlatStubHooks`. Any idea where this is? I've grep'ed the entire code base and there is no definition anywhere. Even searching on the net yields no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'll confirm your `grep` is working, I found only that one reference to it as well, in versions `8.5.15` and `8.4.20`.

What may be of interest is that in `8.6.1`, the definition changes to `void *` as seen below.

```
typedef struct TclPlatStubs {
    int magic;
    void *hooks;

#if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__CYGWIN__) /* WIN */
    TCHAR * (*tcl_WinUtfToTChar) (const char *str, int len, Tcl_DString *dsPtr); /* 0 */
    char * (*tcl_WinTCharToUtf) (const TCHAR *str, int len, Tcl_DString *dsPtr); /* 1 */
#endif /* WIN */
#ifdef MAC_OSX_TCL /* MACOSX */
    int (*tcl_MacOSXOpenBundleResources) (Tcl_Interp *interp, const char *bundleName, int hasResourceFile, int maxPathLen, char *libraryPath); /* 0 */
    int (*tcl_MacOSXOpenVersionedBundleResources) (Tcl_Interp *interp, const char *bundleName, const char *bundleVersion, int hasResourceFile, int maxPathLen,   char *libraryPath); /* 1 */
#endif /* MACOSX */
} TclPlatStubs;
```

Maybe you could get away with treating it as a `void *`?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's something that *used* to point to something real but which no longer needed. If that's so, it is kept as that structure can't be shrunk at all due to Tcl 8.* having a very strict ABI compatibility requirement. (It's initialised to `NULL`…)